# In what scenarios I can get "Application Cache Obsolete event "

Tags: html, html5-appcache, offline-caching

Sometimes my webapp which I have enabled to make it work for offline using HTML5 appache is getting Obsolete event .

```
Application Cache Obsolete event
```

Because of this my cache is getting deleted and webapp stops working.
How can I fix this , basically I am not doing any thing in code so how can I get obsolete event.

How can I stop to get obsolete event?

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc, the event is fired when:

> The manifest was found to have become a 404 or 410 page, so the application cache is being deleted.

That normally mean that your offline app is able to connect to the server to check the manifest, but the server return a 404 or 410 code when the app tries to get the manifest file.

You can read more about the events here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/offline.html